# Postgres: use NULLIF inside query with "WITH data"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm looking for a way to insert NULL on empty string for the field **agency_id** with this query:

```
WITH data(email, agency_id, address, city, zipcode) AS (
    VALUES ('email@domain.tld', '', 'My Address', 'My City', 'My Zipcode')
)

INSERT INTO customers (email, agency_id)
SELECT email, NULLIF(agency_id, '') FROM data
```

In this query **agency_id** must be NULL but with this way it doesn't work.
I'd like to use NULLIF somewhere.

Comment: This is working for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4de2a/1 What is your problem in detail?

Comment: With "integer" I can reproduce my problem: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/690dd/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a type conversion issue, in this case from `VARCHAR` to `INT`. If your table is:

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
    email text NOT NULL,
    agency_id integer NULL
);
```

You need to convert:

- The value `''` to `null`.
- A numeric value in text form such as `'123'` (varchar) to `123` (int).

The following query will work:

```
WITH data(email, agency_id, address, city, zipcode) AS (
    VALUES ('email@domain.tld', '', 'My Address', 'My City', 'My Zipcode')
)
INSERT INTO customers (email, agency_id)
SELECT email, 
  case when agency_id = '' then null
       else agency_id::int
  end 
FROM data;
```